# Laravel get Users->Projects with its ProjectTypes relation, where Users is connected by ManyToMany with ProjectTypes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

How can i get Users->Projects with its ProjectTypes relation, where Users is connected by ManyToMany with  ProjectTypes.

I have this tables:

```
User
- id 
- name

Project
- id
- name

ProjectType
- id
- name

project_type_user
- id
- user_id
- project_type_id

project_user
- id
- user_id
- project_id
```

Now i have this table:

```
auth()->user()->projectTypes

id        type name   project name
$type->id $type->name $type->project->name
```

But i want this table:

```
auth()->user()->projects with projectTypes:
id           project name   project types
$project->id $project->name here iterating over multiple projectsTypes
```

The issue is that when i call `auth()->user()->projectTypes` i'm getting multiple `projectTypes` that have one project, because that i want to get projects with multiple `projectTypes` which are connected by many to many with `users`

Comment: Define a relationship between users and projects. It should be pretty similar to the relationship defined between users and project_types.

Comment: @IGP I have this relation. But i need users-projects that have projecTypes by users->projectsTypes many to many relation

Comment: Use `has` then. `User::has('projectTypes')->with('projects')->get()`?

Comment: @IGP Getting an array of one user `$projects = auth()->user()->has('projectTypes')->with('projects')->get(); dd($projects);`

Comment: Are you trying to get all users or just your Auth user? What if the Auth user has no project types? Can't you do something like `auth()->user()->projectTypes->isNotEmpty() ? auth()->user()->projects : collect();`

Comment: @IGP Just Auth user, see update on question

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I know what you are trying to do and will be building my answer on it. Your structure is fundamentally incorrect if you are trying to list projects with their (multiple) types. Because right now, you have no connection at all between projects and project_types. Therefore, you may need to change the migrations to be:

```
User
- id 
- name

Project
- id
- name

ProjectType
- id
- name
- project_id

project_type_user (DELETE THIS)
- id
- user_id
- project_type_id

project_project_type (NEW)
- id
- project_id
- project_type_id

project_user
- id
- user_id
- project_id
```

What changed was that we cut the direct connection between project_types and users because we can keep the projects as the bridge. Now you can easily use the `projectTypes()` relationship you'll make in the Projects model like:

```
$type->project->projectTypes;
```

Let me know if I completely misinterpreted your structure's purpose.

Comment: project_project_type (NEW)
- id
- project_id
- project_type_id -- but i already have this relation

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention it in your question. Wouldn't following this structure be better for you? Your goal was to iterate over multiple projectsTypes, and $project->projectTypes; would achieve exactly that. Am I missing something?